# naturalHeight and naturalWidth property new or deprecated?

Tags: javascript, dom

`naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` property of `HTMLImageElement` object is not mentioned in mozilla website  [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/img)

Although both properties works fine in Firefox but i don't see this in documentation.

Is it a deprecated property or new in HTML5?

Can someone give me a link where these properties are defined in standard?

Comment: Also, you were looking at the documentation for the HTML `img` tag, rather than the [HTMLImageElement interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement), which mentions `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely not deprecated. Checking the HTML5 spec for the [`img` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element), we can see:

> The IDL attributes naturalWidth and naturalHeight must return the
>   intrinsic width and height of the image, in CSS pixels, if the image
>   is available, or else 0. [CSS]

Comment: the word `intrinsic` is not easy to understand for non-english speaker and it seems a confusing..goggling that word doesn't help much.